# GDAL Python OGRFeature .GetGeometryRef vs .Clone().GetGeometryRef

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal

Just recently I was trying to get the geometry of a polygon stored in an ESRI Shapefile. In the script I was trying to read the polygon as follows:

```
import ogr
path = "shape.shp"
ds = ogr.Open(path, 0)
layer = ds.GetLayer()
layer.GetFeature(0).GetGeometryRef().GetGeometryName()
```

which resulted in a memory access error.

I then tried this:

```
import ogr
path = "shape.shp"
ds = ogr.Open(path, 0)
layer = ds.GetLayer()
layer.GetFeature(0).Clone().GetGeometryRef().GetGeometryName()
```

Which worked.

Why does that work but not the other approach? Which of them is 'right'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The osgeo module is  not really very "Pythonic" (SWIG generated Python bindings for the GDAL and OGR C/C++ libraries)

Your first solution does not work. Why ?
Look at [segfault with Clone() called on GeometryRef of Feature](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2238)

> This is definitely a variable scoping issue. I would call it a bug, but it isn't going to be fixed any time soon. **Please use more verbose method calls to ensure intermediate variables do not go out of scope.**

The log of the crash confirming the precedent remark is

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000090
```

Therefore this more verbose solution work:

```
from osgeo import ogr
ds = ogr.Open("test.shp")
layer = ds.GetLayer(0)
# first feature
feat = layer.GetFeature(0)
geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
print geom.GetGeometryName()
LINESTRING
```

When you use `layer.GetFeature(0).Clone()` you work with a copy of the feature (different) ([OGRFeature * OGRFeature::Clone()](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRFeature.html#a50e56c6f062586f5ab2c091e62dd3801)) with fewer problems.

That is why Sean Gillies creates [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) to "simplify" the Python port of the C/C++ ogr library.

```
import fiona
layer = fiona.open("test.shp")
print layer.schema['geometry']
LineString
# directly
print fiona.open("test.shp").schema['geometry']
LineString
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sadly I cannot use fiona, but in this case python is just fine.